# Encryption with gpg works but not sign-encrypt

Tags: gpg

I made a script that auto backups of my Keepass DB to Google Drive

So first it is encrypted, but I would like signing too

I used 2 systems, a Mac Mini (Intel) (2c/2t, 16G RAM) and a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS (8c/16t, 16G RAM)

Using the same command :

```bsh
gpg -vvv --yes --batch -r <REDACTED> --passphrase-file /home/stig124/pkx --output ~/bak/secbak-140421_20.tar.xz3 --encrypt --sign ~/bak/secbak-140421_2002.tar.xz
```

On the Mac, it works just fine, but on Ubuntu it always fails with the log saying nothing

```
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: key 6CF8D3A4170BD77B: accepted as trusted key
gpg: using subkey 524151A99DEC9CA3 instead of primary key 6CF8D3A4170BD77B
gpg: automatically retrieved <REDACTED> via Local
gpg: This key belongs to us
gpg: writing to '/home/stig124/bak/secbak-140421_20.tar.xz3'
gpg: RSA/AES256 encrypted for: <REDACTED>"
```

It halts on that forever

Removing signing solves the issue but I have absolutely no idea why it is failing, is there a fix possible?

Ubuntu GPG ver. `2.2.19` (latest available on Ubuntu 20.04 repos)

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/stig124/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

MacOS `11.2.3` GPG ver. `2.2.27` (latest GPG Suite-shipped version)

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/stig124/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Answer (score 0):

> gpg -vvv --yes --batch -r  --passphrase-file /home/stig124/pkx --output ~/bak/secbak-140421_20.tar.xz3 --encrypt --sign ~/bak/secbak-140421_2002.tar.xz

If using `--passphrase-file` you also need to include `--pinentry-mode loopback`:

```
gpg -vvv --pinentry-mode loopback --yes --batch -r <REDACTED> --passphrase-file /home/stig124/pkx --output ~/bak/secbak-140421_20.tar.xz3 --encrypt --sign ~/bak/secbak-140421_2002.tar.xz
```